# Are there any language requirements for citizen applicants with low English skills?

Tags: application, united-states, language-exams, toefl

I see from a university website that "if you are not a citizen of one of the following countries..." [a list of countries], "you will need to take the TOEFL before enrolling."  (USA is not on the list, but I presume that's irrelevant).  My friend is a US citizen originally from a different country, and her conversational English is passable, but she absolutely would not pass the TOEFL.

In most schools, could she walk in without the test, because she's (lately) obtained her US citizenship?

Comment: Suppose she were admitted without bringing her English up to the TOEFL level. She would be in a mess. She could not be a TA, which might leave her without funding. She would have trouble following lectures and formulating questions.

Comment: are you asking for US school? US univ would not require US citizen to do TOEFL or equivalent. Proof of language proficiency for international students is to ensure some likelihood of success and to weed out those who would require extensive resources for remediation. While the student described above might end up failing or never being accepted (due to not being able to do well on the SAT or ACT's or GRE's preexams in English) the percentage of citizen applicants accepted but not fluent 'enough' would so small that it would not be time/staff effective to bother to check. They sink or swim.

Comment: Becoming naturalized as a US citizen normally requires an English test. I know someone who went through it - it is a basic test of conversational English and is graded based on whether the examiner can communicate with you. It can be passed with terrible grammar and awkward vocabulary. "I american want to be, i understanding the englishes, know how asks for directions, i know statue of liberty in new york city and must be 18's to votes for president i can be americans?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually, universities set the requirements by native language and/or educational experience in English. If you have a bachelor's or PhD from a US university, they usually waive your language testing requirement because (1) you probably have already passed one many years ago and (2) if you're not good enough at English you probably would not have received your degree.

But if you're just an American citizen, no. They don't usually waive TOEFL just because of your passport. There are many Americans out there who don't even speak English. Of course, if you're an American citizen whose native language is English, you would most certainly not be expected to tale the TOEFL.

Answer (score 0):

I would add to the other user answering your question that, citizenship status do not necessarily waive the language test requirement. Academic institutes have usually these conditions for an applicant to not require him to sit a language test:

He has completed his previous studies in an English speaking institute (either in an English speaking country or not), or the applicant have worked for at least two years in an English speaking environment (an English speaking country, a project which is done in English, etc). The applicant may prove it by presenting a letter written by his/her employer.

Otherwise, whether he is a citizen of that country or not, he has to prove his language skills by presenting a valid test score (which is usually a test he has sit not later than two years before the date he is attending the university. Some other institutes may have more strict conditions depending on the major of study or applicants' conditions).

Even I have read some pages over the net (I am not remembering the exact link to refer to and I think it was among the questions in this site) that citizens who have spent some years outside of the country (for instance they have attended a local non-English speaking school) have to provide a language test for their applications, if the university doubts about his communication skills.